# Javascript, Problema de de length no esta declarado

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, json, nodejs

Tengo el siguiente código Javascript, lo cual declaro 2 parámetros file_input, id.
Como resultado obtengo, al subir una imagen el icono se pinta de color, si quito la imagen se quita el color del icono.
Pero tengo un problema de que el length no esta definido, ¿Me pueden ayudar a resolver este problema?, Porfavor.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    function detectFile(file_input, id) {
        if (file_input.files.length > 0) {
            $('#icon_upload' + id).addClass("green-text");
        } else{
            $('#icon_upload' + id).removeClass("green-text");
        }
    }
</script>

Html

<div class="col-12">
 <input type="file" id="foto1" name="foto1" accept="image/png, .jpeg, .jpg, image/gif;capture=camera" class="input-foto" requered onchange="detectFile(this, 1)"  value="{{foto1_ret}}" >
<label id="input_foto1" class="border rounded col-12 label-foto" for="foto1">
 <i class="fa fa-camera-retro icon_base" id="icon_upload1"></i> Foto 1</label>
</div>
```

Dejo una Imagen igual del html.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
**Se los Agradecería un Monton**

Comment: Edité tu pregunta para poder ejecutar el código aquí (con fragmento de código) y funciona correctamente. Sería conveniente que agregues información del navegador que estás usando, así como otras librerías Javascript (aparte de jQuery).

Comment: Woow gracias, veré como se hace para ejecutar el o los códigos aquí.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error se produce porque estás llamando la función `detectFile()` cuando se carga la página. Y como todavía no se ha elegido un archivo entonces `file_input` es undefined.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    function detectFile(file_input, id) {
        if (file_input.files.length > 0) {
            $('#icon_upload' + id).addClass("green-text");
        } else{
            $('#icon_upload' + id).removeClass("green-text");
        }
    }
    
 window.addEventListener("load",function(){
    detectFile($('#foto1'),1); // aquí está el error.
 });
</script>

Html

<div class="col-12">
 <input type="file" id="foto1" name="foto1" accept="image/png, .jpeg, .jpg, image/gif;capture=camera" class="input-foto" requered onchange="detectFile(this, 1)"  value="{{foto1_ret}}" >
<label id="input_foto1" class="border rounded col-12 label-foto" for="foto1">
 <i class="fa fa-camera-retro icon_base" id="icon_upload1"></i> Foto 1</label>
</div>
```

Comment: En parte es correcta tu respuesta, pero el error principal es la forma de evaluar, debería ser: `$(file_input).val() == ''` para saber si se seleccionó un archivo, porque no tiene el atributo _multiple_ o, en todo caso: `$(file_input).get(0).files.length > 0`

Comment: Eso depende del contexto. En el caso actual la función está vinculada con el evento `onchange`, eso asegura que `files` no será undefined, posiblemente llamarla en el load de la página sea un error.  En caso no lo sea, como dices, hay que cambiar la forma de validación. Agrego otra usando encadenamiento opcional:  `file_input.files?.length > 0`

Comment: Muchas Gracias, por sus respuestas a todos Masters del Javascript. Problema Solucionado  $(file_input).get(0).files.length > 0